# Microphone not picking up the voice!

Tags: sound, microphone

I brought a BY-M1 Pro microphone: https://boya-mic.com/product/by-m1-pro
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

My PC motherboard info is:

Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC
Product Name: TUF GAMING B660M-E D4

In my *Settings* -> *Sound* -> *Input* it shows "Front Microphone - Built-in Audio" or "Rear Microphone - Built-in Audio", so I think the microphone is connected but the voice is not taken?
How can I solve this issue?

Sound settings:

[image: my sound settings show]